# Kotlin Spring JPA Reactive overcoming the default exception

Tags: kotlin, exception, spring-data-jpa, reactive-programming, spring-jdbc

I had a problem which was, 
When have a unique constraint in the DB query,

and then want to insert it again,
I wanted to override the default exception.

like when having a DB table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $ENROLLED_USERS_TABLE (
                    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    $USERS_FIELD VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL UNIQUE
                );
```

and the repo like this

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository: ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Int>{

    @Modifying
    @Query("insert into $ENROLLED_USERS_TABLE ($USERS_FIELD) values (:user)")
    fun insertUser(@Param("user") user: String?): Mono<Void?>?
}
```

this is my controller

```
@PostMapping("/{user}")
    suspend fun add(@PathVariable user:String): Void? = userRepository.insertUser(user)?.awaitFirstOrNull()
```

I have tried to put them in try and catch but it didn't work
to catch the

```
@Service
class UserService(val userRepository: UserRepository) {

    suspend fun add(user:String) {
        try {
            // some code
            userRepository.insertUser(user)?.onErrorReturn(throw ResourceAlreadyExists("User Already exists"))

        }
        catch (e: SQLException) {
            println("Custome Message")
        }
    }
}
```

nothing worked I still get the exception that shows my database query :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was simple

```
@PostMapping("/{user}")
    suspend fun add(@PathVariable user:String): Void? = userRepository.insertUser(user)?.onErrorMap { throw ResourceAlreadyExists("User Already Exists") }?.awaitFirstOrNull()
```

mapping the error was the right one